# Check if a file exists with a wildcard

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to check if certain files exist in a directory prior to copying a file over.
For the files that are always the same I am using FileExists method.  The issue I have is 2 of the files I'm looking for vary from day to day, PTmmddyy for example.
I know the FileExists will not accept wildcards.  Is there some other way.
I'm pretty novice at this and have attempted using a Dir and Len command with no luck as well as IO.Directory.GetFiles with no luck.

Given some input, I did some digging on the WMI, which is way above my head.  I think I've got how it should work but am still getting an error.  I've modified my code below and am now getting an error on the If chkpt.Count > 0 line but it specifies Bad Query.  I've looked and can't figure out what the issue is with the ExecQuery

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading=1, ForWriting=2, ForAppending=8
'--------------------------------------------
'Checking for existing transaction files

Dim targetdir
targetdir = "\\pet-sagesql\f$\v2016\Sage100P\MAS90\MAS_PCS\clpcs\"

'Checking to see if there are any files already available to process
Dim chkloc
Set chkloc = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If chkloc.FileExists(targetdir & "Locbill.csv") Then
Wscript.Echo "Sorry, there is already a Locbill file to process"
Wscript.Quit
End If

targetcp = "pet-sagesql"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & targetcp & "\root\cimv2")

Set chkpt = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From CIM_Datafile Where _ 
FileName LIKE ‘f:\\v2016\\Sage100p\\MAS90\\MAS_PCS\\CLPCS\\PT%'")


If chkpt.Count > 0 Then
Wscript.Echo "Sorry, there is already a PT file to process"
Wscript.Quit
End If
```

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052900/vbscript-to-check-for-the-existance-of-a-file-with-the-ability-to-use-a-wildcar

Comment: @peter nice find, but what's stopping you from flagging as a duplicate rather then just posting the link?